# How to use next/link with functional component and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, material-ui

I want to pass the href given to Nextjs Link tag (`` <NextLink href={`/${linkTag}`} passHref> ``) to my custom  tag, but typescript complains that it can't find href attribute.

I was referencing this doc https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component.

Following is the current state of my code (with removal of unnecessary code).

```
import { Box, Typography, Button, SvgIconTypeMap } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { OverridableComponent } from "@mui/material/OverridableComponent";
import NextLink, { LinkProps } from "next/link";

interface ListItemProps {
  text: string;
  icon: OverridableComponent<SvgIconTypeMap<{}, "svg">>;
  linkTag: string;
}

interface ListItemContainerProps {
  children: React.ReactChild | Array<React.ReactChild>;
}

type ListItemSubContainerProps = {
  children: React.ReactChild | Array<React.ReactChild>;
} & LinkProps;

const ListItemContainer = ({ children }: ListItemContainerProps) => (
  <Box>{children}</Box>
);

const ListItemSubContainer = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLAnchorElement,
  ListItemSubContainerProps
>(({ children, href }: ListItemSubContainerProps, ref) => (
  <Box ref={ref} href={href as string | undefined} component="a">
    {children}
  </Box>
));

const ListItem = ({ icon: Icon, linkTag }: ListItemProps) => {
  return (
    <ListItemContainer>
      <NextLink href={`/${linkTag}`} passHref>
        <ListItemSubContainer>
          <Icon />
        </ListItemSubContainer>
      </NextLink>
    </ListItemContainer>
  );
};

export default ListItem;
```

I get the following error.

`Property 'href' is missing in type '{ children: Element; }' but required in type 'LinkProps'.`

when calling `<ListItemSubContainer>` in the return portion.

Any help, or recommendation will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to pass href as a prop -> <ListItemSubContainer href={...}>

Comment: @J.dev won't NextLink do that on it's own? I was following the nextjs doc (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-functional-component)

Comment: @fathomless You're right in that it feeds it. Link is just a HOC and passHref enables the props. Try dropping LinkProps from the ListItemSubContainerProps type. Does that work?

Comment: @Tom No, it doesn't work then, now it complains that href doesn't exist in the function component prameter list. But if I pass ```href={`/${linkTag}`}``` with ListItemSubContainer everything works. But my point was that NextLink should pass it, why do I have to do it manually.

Comment: The reason is because you're overriding the default behaviour with your wrapper component, I don't think you can use the LinkProps type in any meaningful way. 

Just change the type

```ListItemSubContainerProps = {
  children: React.ReactChild | Array<React.ReactChild>;
  href: string;
};```

Comment: @Tom Ok I changed it as you said, but I still don't understand why NextLink can't forward the href to it's child as shown in the docs, and why can't typescript pick that up.

Comment: Right now, I moved the NextLink tag inside ListItemSubContainer  and removed the forwardRef, things are much simplier now and everything works fine. But still if anyone can explain why the code in question didn't work, I would be very happy to hear the reason.